# How to mask an html element using an image

Tags: html, css

I'm making a game. In the bottom left will be the players health. I want to represent this health by showing an outline of a human body where the health value is a gradient image that is filled in and when they drop health that gradient image will be shifted downward to let the background show through.

I have the following code but all I see is the gradient image in the div and it's not masked by the mask which is a black and white image. What am I doing wrong with this? I'm using chrome and that's the only browser I need this to support.

```
html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    #footer{
        position: fixed;
        left: 10px;
        bottom: 10px;
    }

 <body style="background-color: gray;">
    <div id="footer" style="width: 15%; height: 25vw; background-color: red; ">
        <img src="http://www.adamdorman.com/wallpaper/gradient_1600x1200.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; mask: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/Layer-masks-mask.jpg);" />
    </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bwh3couo/

Comment: You should probably apply the mask on a container element, such as <span>. i.e. `<span style=""><img></span>`

Comment: please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or a code snippet.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bwh3couo/

Comment: you can look into [clipPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath)

Comment: @maioman that looks interesting but I would have to create by human body outline from primitives? That might be a little hard. I'd much rather prefer using an image for the clipping.

Comment: you could also use it with an exported svg (from a vector graphic software - like illustrator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would suggest to use a png of a human figure which is **transparent inside and opaque outside** (meaning the human body is transparent and the frame around it is opaque e.g white or sth) than have a div beneath it (with same width) which can be changed height as needed and is of specific color (or gradient), then it will seem as though the body is filling or emptying of strength.

**Note** this is cross-browser solution not requiring css masks per se.

e.g http://www.doorway-to-self-esteem.com/images/human_figure_copyr.jpg

To use a full css/svg mask you can check the following links:

1. https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/
2. http://unakravets.tumblr.com/post/50352178165/creating-a-truly-cut-out-div
3. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

> **The difference between clipping and masking**
>
> Masks are images; Clips are paths.
>
> Imagine a square image that is a left-to-right, black-to-white
>   gradient. That can be a mask. The element it is applied to will be
>   transparent (see-through) where there is black in our gradient mask
>   image, and opaque (normal) where there is white. So the final result
>   will be an element that fades in from left to right.
>
> Clips are always vector paths. Outside the path is transparent, inside
>   the path is opaque.
>
> ...There was a WebKit-only version of masking where you could link up a
>   raster image or define a gradient to be a mask. ... More modern
>   references I've found only mention masks as being defined in SVG and
>   referenced in CSS by ID or URL.

Specificaly to use an image as a (clipping) mask you would need to transform the image into a vector (.svg) using a program like illustrator or [similar](http://www.autotracer.org/) and do the folowing:

**html**

```
<div id="masked" class="mask this-has-gradient"></div>
```

**css**

```
.mask {
  mask: url(human-body.svg);
}
```

**other options for masking**

```
.mask {
  mask-type: luminance; /* white = transparent, grays = semi-transparent, black = opaque */
  mask-type: alpha; /* transparent areas of the image let image through, otherwise not */
}
```

**update adding another approach** (works with .png image not needing .svg)

adapted from [here](http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking)

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
svg#svg-masked
{
  width: 307px;
  height:486px;
}
.masked
{
  width: 307px;
  height:486px;
  background: #00f;
}
</style>
<title>SVG masking/clipping</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- SVG begins -->
<svg id="svg-masked">
<!-- Definition of a mask begins -->
<defs>
<mask id="mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <image width="307px" height="486px" xlink:href="human_body2.png"></image>
</mask>
</defs>
<!-- Definition of a mask ends -->
<foreignObject width="307px" height="486px" style="mask:url(#mask);">
<!-- HTML begins -->
<div class="masked"></div>
<!-- HTML ends -->
</foreignObject>
</svg>
<!-- SVG ends -->
</body>
</html>
```

**human_body2.png**

[image]

**result** (tested on firefox and chrome)

[image]

The apporach wraps the html element inside an `svg` element which uses an `image` as a (luminance) mask

Comment: So almost the reverse of what I'm talking about huh. The issue is that outside of the human body has to be transparent but not show the gradient background. This is because I write this to a buffer for a 3D engine as this is the UI for a game. So that part can't be a rectangle of a color. It has to be transparent so it shows the game behind it.

Comment: hmm, then take a look at masking using css and/or canvas/svg, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/, https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/ most probably you will have to turn the human body into vector path and use that in clipping/masking

Comment: Yeah that's what I was looking at and they talk about this img {
  mask-image: url(mask.svg);
} but when I used that I don't see to see anything. I was using a png but I guess I assumed an image is an image and a png mask would work as well.

Comment: i think you can use a program (e.g illustrator or similar) to transform the image into a vector/svg and export it

Comment: So no getting around needing to convert the image to svg huh. I'll have to figure out a way to do that for free if possible.

Comment: So I converted and now have the following but still now seeing anything. I might be confusing where the image goes. <div id="footer" style="width: 15%; height: 25vw; background-color: red; background-image: url(gradient_1600x1200.jpg); mask: url(Layer_masks_mask.svg);">

Comment: @user441521, better add all this in a css style to make sure the correct paths are resolved, the svg should define the path of the body not the whole colored image. Try to setup a fiddle and see what's going on

Comment: I was able to convert with your first link. I don't have a way right now to upload the svg online to use it with a fiddle example. Will have to wait for a few hours when I have access to some online storage.

Comment: @user441521, this made me curious and trying to achieve a masking with svg myself, in the meanwhile check this also http://unakravets.tumblr.com/post/50352178165/creating-a-truly-cut-out-div

Comment: I find it interesting that when I'm in VS doing this mask-type: isn't an option from the intellisense. Yeah, I can't get this going locally in Chrome :(

Comment: Wait I got it working with that mask-box-image! I had the png instead of the svg. When I put the svg in it worked!

Comment: @user441521, great i also added another approach which uses the .png image directly (but wraps the div element inside an svg element). Tested in firefox and chrome

Comment: I can't see your images but I see the code. Now the interesting thing is how do you lower the background image so it looks like the health is dropping?

Comment: @user441521, you just change the background color/gradient of the `.masked` div, the rest remains as is. Or you use 2 divs and just change their relative heights. one with a `strength` color and another with a `missing-strength` color (updated answer with images hope you can see)

Comment: It looks like I can put a div inside this one and grow it's height like: <div style="background-color: black; width: 100%; height: 50%;">

        </div> it also is clipped!

Comment: @user441521, yes the whole element is clipped (and everything inside it) as is expected